# Consume and output SOAP web service using Drupal 7 Web service client and Rules

Tags: drupal, soap, wsdl, drupal-rules

I need to get data from WSDL service and output into existing Drupal 7 CCK fields.

**How can I output information from WSDL into existing CCK fields or simply with PHP in templates with or without Rules module?**

1. I attentively learned and tried example described in [Consume SOAP web service using Web service client and Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1114308)
2. Also I learn question in [WSDL, XML, SOAP, PHP, and Drupal.... Oh my!](https://www.drupal.org/node/1956822)

*Never have worked before with SOAP and WSDL and have idea how I can fulfil the process of working with Drupal 7 and CCK fields.*